# Adding character to a string in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, split

So let's say I have string like this

> ' one,two,3,four'

I need to add " **'** " for each word in between the quotes, so at the end I need to get a back a single string like this

> ' 'one','two','3','four'

I know I can split the whole string with **split** function in **sql** but my real question is how can I add those quotes. I appreciate the help of all

Comment: mysql or sql server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `replace()` and string concatenation.  In standard SQL, this looks like:

```
select '''' || replace(str, ',', ''',''') || ''''
```

MySQL and SQL Server use different methods for string concatenation, so this would typically be written as:

```
select concat('''', replace(str, ',', ''','''), '''')
```

or

```
select '''' + replace(str, ',', ''',''') + ''''
```

Answer (score 2):

Double the quote when you use them.

Multiple columns:

`SELECT '''one''', '''two''', '''3''' , '''four'''`

Single String

`SELECT '''one'', ''two'', ''3'',  ''four'''`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `quotename`, `string_agg` (starting from SQL Server 2017) and    `string_split` (from SQL Server 2016):

```
declare @string nvarchar(max)=' one,two,3,four'

select '''' + string_agg(quotename(trim(value), ''''), ',') as result
from string_split(@string,',')
```

Result:

[image]